# Verbal noun of pure copula - logical implications?

Tags: nouns, copular-verbs

In her emendation of her earlier work on antilogism [here](https://archive.org/stream/jstor-2013355/2013355#page/n1/mode/2up), Christine Ladd-Franklin wrote

> ... That no human beings are immortal and no angels are mortal
>   precludes any angels being human.

[She then presents the syllogism in symbolic form]

> The formula says "precludes that any angels (some angels) are human"
>   but rhetoric has a strong penchant for 
>    turning the verb of a subordinate proposition into a verbal noun.

Is her point that the verbal (being) implies more existential import than the pure copula as a verb (is/are), or am I missing something?

Comment: See also [linguistics.se]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think she is implying any deeper meaning; she is merely acknowledging (presumably to forestall objections) the apparent inconsistency of expressing the subject of her sentence with a *that* clause and its object with a *gerund* clause.

She attributes this inconsistency to ‘rhetoric’, which is accurate only if you take ‘rhetoric’ to mean ‘the art of verbal expression’. I believe that a linguist would call the preference of *preclude* for gerund clausal complements a licensing constraint. Mamma English don't allow no *preclude that* playing round here.<sup>†</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> Which is not to say that she has no naughty children; but the construction is [very rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=precludes+that%2Fprecludes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28precludes%20that%20/%20precludes%29%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: *That Mama don't allow it don't preclude JJ playing his guitar or me writing this sentence.* But have I struck a blow for linguistic freedom from interfering "grammar gerund Nazi mamas" by using ***me*** instead of ***my*** there? I have the distinct feeling *me = continuous verb*, whereas *my = gerund noun*. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the whole point of the participle/gerund is that it is both at once. But I agree  that *my* marks the p/g as nounier and *me* as verbier. I think there are bunch of posts floating around on the POSS-gerund *vs* OBJ-gerund thing.

Comment: Well, your substantive point in the answer is obviously correct *(That the first proposition starts with "that" doesn't imply the second adopting the same form)*. But however the propositions are actually expressed, I think they inevitably have a certain amount of nouniness (and there was me thinking *verbing* weirds language, but I now see *nouning* is just as capable of doing the job! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers They have to have that nouniness to act as subjects and objects - or as propositions. All the way back in Philosophy 101 I remember thinking that we'd think about everything very differently if Plato and Aristotle had used verbs instead of nouns for their key terms.

Comment: Good point! Even today we speak of *particle* physics and *string* theory at the leading edge, but the more I try to get my head around such things the more it seems to be all about *vibrating, moving, being perceived, having an effect,* etc. Reality does increasingly seem to be a matter of *things **happening*** rather than ***things** existing*.